# Tensorflow: How to determine the value of clip_norm when using clip_by_norm or clip_by_global_norm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I am trying to find out how to determine the value of `clip_norm` when using [clip_by_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_norm) or [clip_by_global_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_global_norm) with Tensorboard.

In Tensorflow, we can use the optimizer to `compute_gradients` to obtain the gradient and add it to the [tf.summary.histogram](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/histogram). In Tensorboard, we can observe the range of the gradient in the `DISTRIBUTIONS` tab. Then we can determine the `clip_value` range when using [clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value).

On the other hand, how shall I calculate/display the norm or global norm in Tensorboard  so that I can determine the value of `clip_norm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view norm or global norm in Tensorboard you can manually calculate it.

For the norm (not global) you obtain gradient as usual using `compute_gradients` and compute gradient l2 norm using [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm). This gives you a scalar value. You can add it to Tensorboard using [`tf.summary.scalar`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar).

For the global norm you can compute it using [`tf.global_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_norm) and then add it to Tensorboard (also scalar summary).

**EDIT**:

Please note that [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) expects single tensor. So you need to compute norm and add to to Tensorboard for each gradients tensor. The same as you do when using `tf.summary.histogram` to view values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your suggestion, I tried to obtain gradient using `grads, vars = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))` and use `tf.global_norm(grads)`, it is running okay. However, if I tried to do the same thing with `tf.norm(grads)` it throws the following error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 4 and 1. Please kindly suggest how to fix this as I cannot find the usage of `tf.norm` with `compute_gradients` online.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found that I can add the norm for each gradient tensor to both the scalar and histogram. Does it make sense to add to the histogram (e.g. norm for weight, bias, batch_norm will be added to the histogram)?

Comment: @chesschi, everything that you find interesting / useful / convenient makes sense